# Повадно ли такое словотворчество?

Tags: приставки

Льзя ли применять слова без отрицательной приставки?

Comment: можно, но не нужно :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Льзя, если таковые существуют без отрицательной приставки.
`Повадно` существует как отдельное слово:

> А нам, мечтателям, и вовсе повадно играть в эту игру. [[Юрий Архипов. Назову себя шахматистом… (2004) // «64 — Шахматное обозрение», 2004.05.15]](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CF%EE%E2%E0%E4%ED%EE&docid=8213)

`Льзя` тоже существует, хотя многие о его существовании не подозревают.

> Потом переписал очень хорошие стишки:
>
> "Душеньки часок не видя,
>
> Думал, год уж не видал;
>
> Жизнь мою возненавидя,
>
> Льзя ли жить мне, я сказал".
>
> [[Н. В. Гоголь. Записки сумасшедшего (1835)]](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EB%FC%E7%FF&docid=85754)

Существует и [`впопад`](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%EF%EE%EF%E0%E4&docid=46151). Однако надо не забывать, что такие слова при их употреблении вызывают у читателей и слушателей некоторое недоумение и поэтому являются стилистически маркированными, их употребление в стилистически нейтральном тексте не оправдано, поскольку они привносят в текст элемент поэтики и словотворчества. Ну и без "не" не употребляются, например, "забудка", "нависть", "ожиданность", "настье", "истовство", "дотёпа", "дотрога" и многие другие слова.

Answer (score 5):

Речь (письменная и устная), как процесс письма или говорения обычно не является самоцелью. Обычно люди хотят донести свои мысли до собеседника. Поэтому правило в словотворчестве по большому счету одно: нужно говорить и писать так, чтобы понял собеседник.

Письменная и устная речь по-разному справляются с отклонениями от стандарта. Люди обладающие хорошим навыком чтения читают слова (а то и целые предложения) с одного взгляда, не прочитывая все буквы слова. Если же слово необычное - скорость чтения снижается. Пишут что нормальный темп чтения сохраняется если количество ошибок в тексте не больше определенного уровня (если я не ошибаюсь, ошибки в 10% слов). Т.е. если рассматривать слова без отрицательной приставки как ошибки - если их будет не слишком много, текст будет восприниматься без труда.

Устная речь (особенно импровизированная) порождает "неправильные конструкции" постоянно, так как говорящий в короткое время должен решить множество задач чтобы получившаяся фраза была правильной. Обычно фраза рождается в процессе говорения и иногда получается так, что договорив до конца фразы, говорящий обнаруживает что в "стандартном" языке не удается подобрать слово в нужном времени, нужного рода и т.п., так как его или не существует или его никак не удается вспомнить. В этом случае появившееся вдруг слово "впопад" или "дотрога" будет нормально воспринято собеседником.

То есть и в устной, и в письменной речи допускается определенное количество "неправильных" слов. Если же таких слов станет слишком много, может произойти "коммуникативная неудача" - вас просто не поймут.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю к верно сказанному выше, что следует помнить, что наличие "не-" в начале не всегда есть отрицательные приставка, ибо есть, скажем, "недо-", которое приводит в том числе к глаголам, которые могут начинаться с "не", как, например, "недоедать" в значении "есть маловато" (в противоположность "не доедать", если имеется в виду "не доесть что-то").
Часть слов не употребляется без "не" не по немного менее очевидной причине, что это не "не-", а часть "недо-", которое нельзя изъять из слова частично. И слова "недотёпа", "недотрах", "недопонимание" и прочие тому пример.

Comment: Всё так, но насчёт слова "недотёпа" я должен с вами не согласиться, в украинском языке есть слова «дотеп» (шутка), «дотепний» (остроумный), «дотепа» (способность; способный человек) от праславянского «*dotьpьnъ» (касательный, проницательный).